# Navigation Helper C# Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have been reading and following a book called Head First C# and in some of the exercises I have come across with something I have not being able to use:  The "Navigation Helper" 
On the book they tell you to type the following code:

```
public MainPage()
{ 
   this.InitializeComponent();
   this.navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper(this)
   this.navigationHelper.LoadState += navigationHelper_LoadState;
   this.navigationHelper.SaveState += navigationHelper_SaveState;
}
```

I'm not sure if it is because the book is supposed to be follow using Window Store app in Visual Studio Express 2013 an I'm using Blank App(Windows Universal) in Visual Studio 2017 but for some reason I don't find the NavigationHelper Class. Am I missing some assembly perhaps? or is it the difference in the templates or versions I'm using? 
if that's the case does anyone knows how to use Windows Store app in VS2017? is that even possible?

I have tried to search for it but I seem not able to find anything online, so this is my last resource :)
Thanks and I'll appreciate any help!

Comment: Are you sure that's not defined elsewhere in the book? I'm pretty sure Microsoft doesn't add `Helper` to framework classes

Comment: Just as I guessed: look [here](https://github.com/head-first-csharp/third-edition/blob/237cb4449d819061670749ee6809fd442e2ceabc/VS2013/Chapter_14/JimmysComicsSplitApp/JimmysComicsSplitApp/Common/NavigationHelper.cs). That's a class the book itself introduces.

Comment: No Wonder I was not able to find anything online hahahaha Thanks! But...how am I suppose to use the class then? any ideas? do I have to include that code in my Project by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue as you described with "Navigation Helper".
Based on the comment written by Camilo Terevinto I did some investigations and refactoring of my code. The results are below, hope it may be useful for you and others:

1) in the link quoted by Camilo there is a deep explanation of this subject and class itself. Look at the line 23-57. There, the author explained what should we do in order to use this class. Because it may be "mission impossible" for the "very beginners" to implement it, let me suggest another solution….which I checked and it worked...
2) refactor your code and comment the lines including missing class and generating errors, for instance:

```
this.navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper(this);
this.navigationHelper.LoadState += navigationHelper_LoadState;
this.navigationHelper.aveState += navigationHelper_SaveState;
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    navigationHelper.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    navigationHelper.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
}
```

This exercise ("Save the Humans" app) in the chapter 1 is rather to understand the process, XEML, etc. Later on you will understand more and more and you will figure out better solution for you.
It worked for me. Please keep on mind that it is not the best solution of the problem, but at least it will allow you to proceed with this lesson and develop this Save the Homans app. 
So please save us!:)

Comment: Thanks a lot! @JaRek I didn't think anybody would reply by now but you did and with a great explanation, I kinda stop reading a book and took some other online courses, i guess I'll be getting back to it now that i have a better undertanding. Again, thanks!

Comment: No problem @dreamheart. Do not give up on this tutorial. It is quite good in my opinion. I'm doing it now, and I'm just few lectures ahead of where you stopped. You may come across another inconsistencies or problems, at least I did while doing this tutorial, but we will manage it till the end I hope. Keeping the fingers crossed. Peace.

Comment: Thanks, I have been advancing on the book, I end up realizing after advancing further that my problem was that i was building the app on a different platform or type of project as intended, that's why I was encountering so many problems, the app is meant to be created on Window Store App (Which I didn't have), instead I was using WPF, at the end of the book they show you how to build the apps for WPF (All problems gone XD ). Btw another great book that has been helping me is C# 6.0 in a nutshell, I highly recommend it.